# How to convert date to Julian date in Dart

Tags: dart, julian-date

I need convert Julian Data gets from my API to Gregorian date like this:

Input 2023150
Output 2023-May-30

How can this be done?

Comment: That "julian date" isn't anything I recognize.  Can you explain what it is?  I'm guessing it means "2023, day 150", but I've never seen that used anywhere, and it doesn't seem to be any standard I recall.  EDIT: Ahh, it's the DateFormat('yyyyDDD') perhaps.

Comment: Are used in fortran crop simulation models, your data inputs are this way. Ex: 2012001
2012002
2012003
2012004

Comment: @RandalSchwartz https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day

Comment: @jamesdlin I looked at that, and none of them were in the right range, and then I noticed that 2023 looks like the current year, and determined day 150 is May 30th, and put them together.

Answer (score 0):

For actual Julian Day conversion, you can use:

```dart
// Noon of 1st of January, 4713 BC in the Julian calendar,
// or the 24th of November, 4713 BC in the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
final _julianEpoch = DateTime.utc(-4713, 11, 24, 12);

/// Convert UTC [DateTime] to, possibly fractional, Julian day.
double toJulian(DateTime gregorianDay) {
  if (!gregorianDay.isUtc) {
    throw ArgumentError.value(gregorianDay, "gregorianDay", "Must be UTC date");
  }
  return gregorianDay.difference(_julianEpoch).inMilliseconds /
      Duration.millisecondsPerDay;
}

/// Convertes, possibly fractional, Julian day value to UTC [DateTime].
DateTime fromJulian(num julianDay) {
  return _julianEpoch.add(Duration(
      milliseconds: (julianDay * Duration.millisecondsPerDay).floor()));
}
```

It seems that what you have is just `year * 1000 + day-in-year`.
Converting that to a day should be easier:

```dart
DateTime fromDayInYear(int yearAndDayInYear) =>
  DateTime.utc(yearAndDayInYear ~/ 1000, 1, yearAndDayInYear.remainder(1000));
```

Comment: As an input I put 2023001, its output should be 2023-01-01 but it is outputting 0826-09-08 12:00:00.000Z

Comment: @lrn Yeah, you made the same mistake I did.  This is not really "julian day" just numbered day of year.

Comment: ACK, will add code that works for the actual user issue as well.